# $x_n = \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{n + jp + 1}{n + jp}$

Tags: limits, solution-verification

Let $p$ be an integer with $p \geq 2$ and define a sequence by $$x_n = \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{n + jp + 1}{n + jp}$$ for each positive integer $n$. Assuming $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ exists, evaluate it.

Here is my thought process. I would like to know if I am correct:

To evaluate the limit of the sequence $x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$, we can simplify the product expression:

$x_n = \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{n + jp + 1}{n + jp}.$

Let's look at the factors in the product:

$\begin{align*}
\frac{n + 0p + 1}{n + 0p} &= \frac{n + 1}{n} = 1 + \frac{1}{n}, \\
\frac{n + 1p + 1}{n + 1p} &= \frac{n + p + 1}{n + p} = 1 + \frac{1}{n + p}, \\
\frac{n + 2p + 1}{n + 2p} &= \frac{n + 2p + 1}{n + 2p} = 1 + \frac{1}{n + 2p}, \\
&\vdots \\
\frac{n + (n-1)p + 1}{n + (n-1)p} &= \frac{n + (n-1)p + 1}{n + (n-1)p} = 1 + \frac{1}{n + (n-1)p}.
\end{align*}$

Now, let's take the product of all these terms:

$x_n = \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1 + \frac{1}{n + p}\right) \left(1 + \frac{1}{n + 2p}\right) \cdots \left(1 + \frac{1}{n + (n-1)p}\right).$

We want to evaluate the limit as $n$ approaches infinity:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1 + \frac{1}{n + p}\right) \left(1 + \frac{1}{n + 2p}\right) \cdots \left(1 + \frac{1}{n + (n-1)p}\right).$

Now, we can use the fact that the limit of a product is the product of the limits (if they exist):

$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n + p}\right) \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n + 2p}\right) \cdots \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n + (n-1)p}\right).$

Each of these individual limits is easy to compute:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) = 1,$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n + p}\right) = 1,$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n + 2p}\right) = 1,$

and so on.

Since each individual limit is equal to 1, the overall limit is:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdots 1 = 1.$

So, $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ exists and is equal to 1.

Comment: The number of factors grows so you cannot apply the product of the limits rule. Besides the limit is nonzero.

Comment: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1 + \frac{1}{n + p}\right)  \cdots \left(1 + \frac{1}{n + (n-1)p}\right)\right)$$
$$\neq\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n+p}\right)\right)\cdots\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n+(n-1)p}\right)\right)$$

Comment: In my first comment I meant the limit is not equal $1.$ Concerning your (wrong) method the limit of $2=(2^{1/n})^n$ would be equal $1.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**  *(it may be too advanced)*

If I may suggest, rewrite first
$$x_n = \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{n + jp + 1}{n + jp}=\frac{\prod_{j=0}^{n-1} {(n+1) + j\,p } } {\prod_{j=0}^{n-1} {n + j\,p } }$$

When you face something like
$$P_k=\prod_{j=0}^k (a+b\,j)$$ rewrite it as
$$P_k=\prod_{j=0}^k (a+b\,j)=\prod_{j=0}^k b \left(\frac{a}{b}+j\right)=\prod_{j=0}^k  b \,\,\prod_{j=0}^k \left(\frac{a}{b}+j\right)=b^{k+1}\,\frac{a \left(\frac{a+b}{b}\right)_k}{b}$$
where $\left(\frac{a+b}{b}\right)_k$ is the Pochhammer symbol. But,using the gamma function
$$\left(\frac{a+b}{b}\right)_k=\frac{\Gamma \left(k+\frac{a}{b}+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{a}{b}+1\right)}$$ which finally gives
$$P_k=b^{k+1}\,\,\frac{ \Gamma \left(k+1+\frac{a}{b}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}$$

Back to the definition of $x_n$

- for both numerator and denominator $k=n-1$ and $b=p$
- for the numerator $a=(n+1)$
- for the denominator $a=n$

So, as a result
$$x_n=\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{n+1}{p}\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n}{p}\right)}{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{n}{p}\right)
   \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{p}\right)}$$

Now, take logarithms, use four times Stirling approximation, finish with Taylor series to have an expansion of $\log(x_n)$ and from there, reuse Taylor since
$$x_n=e^{\log(x_n)}$$

You will obtain a nice and simple expression for the limit.